# How to see where document is linked from?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, search-results

I've got requirement for SharePoint Online, which says that user after performing search is able to see where document is linked from (i.e. in hover panel).

1. When documents are returned via Search, user can hover or click to see which page(s) this document is linked to.
2. Displayed page url is hyperlinked, enabling user to click on link and be directed to page

I was previously advised that this is not possible but maybe some of you will have idea how to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to display the Path managed property? That would be pretty easy since it is already being presented as the link to the document. Just modify the Display Template and surface the Path as text.

Comment: Hi Matthew,
I mean to find locations where document has been linked, i.e. all pages where link to the document is present

Comment: Oh, there used to be a feature (in publishing I think) that showed links to a page, but I have not see links to a doc.)